# What is this encoding \u0641\u0648\u0627\u0632

Tags: php, encoding, decode

When I get JSON data from server in xcode if result content arabic character it shows like this

```
\u0641\u0648\u0627\u0632
```

What encoding is this? How can i decode it ?

Comment: That's not encryption. it's encoded unicode sequences.

Comment: ^- you get rid of it by json_decode-ing the string.

Comment: how can i convert it to text by using php ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like unicode characters (arabic symbols in this case)

Comment: how can i convert it to text by using php

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u0644\u0633\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0627\u062f\u0631 \u062d\u0643\u0627\u064a\u0627\u062a \u0645\u062c\u0646\u0648\u0646\u0647 *\u0627\u0644\u0628\u064a\u0647 \u062a\u0628\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0647\u064a\u0626\u0647*';
$converted = preg_replace('/\\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $str);
echo $converted;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unicode character sequence,
You can use the tool in the following link to Decode it

https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

Answer (score 1):

\u0641\u0648\u0627\u0632

The encoded string you provided appears to be in Unicode escape sequence format, where each character is represented by its Unicode code point in the form of `\uXXXX`. To decode this string and display the result, you can use the [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). However, `json_decode()` expects the input to be in valid JSON format, so we need to wrap the encoded string in double quotes to make it valid JSON.

```php
$encodedString = '"\u0641\u0648\u0627\u0632"';
$decodedString = json_decode($encodedString);
echo $decodedString; // فواز
```